# CSS centering an image in portrait or landscape mode for a 100vh landing page

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am trying to create a landing page for my website. The size of the landing is always the height of the device or 100vh with an arrow at the bottom to scroll the user to content below. I want my face to be in the center of that landing div. Positioning it has not been very difficult on desktop because I leave the image relatively small in the center of the screen, but on mobile where either portrait view is very long and skinny or landscape is wide but short I am not sure how to position my image and text so they work consistently across a number of devices.

[image]

```
<div class="landing">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="image.svg">
        <h1>My Name</h1>
        <p>Small tagline</p>
    </div>
</div>

.landing {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
    width: 300px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    img {
        width: ?
        height: ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code. HTML and CSS.

Comment: I've thrown out the css for the landing image on mobile and am looking to start from scratch.

Comment: Please, post your HTML then.

Comment: Updated with the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with flexbox ?

It's an example. Hope its help.

```css
content{
  height : 100vh;
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content : space-around;
}
.logo{
  flex:1 1 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction :column;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items : center;
}

.ex{
  flex:2;
  display : flex;
}
.ex p{
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="logo"><img src="image.svg">
      <h1>My Name</h1></div>
      <div class="ex"><p>Small tagline</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer, I got it to work with minimal fiddling to my own elements. I would recommend this approach to anyone trying to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Glad it helps !